# Laravel select list without some options

Tags: laravel-5, twig

I created a new column in DB, so I can check whether an option in select list should be visible or not, but I can not figure out how do I actually show only options with "visible" in DB.

My code is:

```
{!! Form::select('establishment_id[]', [], null) !!}
```

I guess I have to modify something in controller also. It just pulls all the data it should, but how do I limit the select list to only show options with "visible" present in DB?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have an attribute that says if the row should be visible in the select or not? I'm trying to understand but as far as I can see you need `Model::where('visible', false)->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->all()` type of thing.

Comment: I am totally new to laravel so I do not fully understand the architecture yet. I created a row in database which has "visible" value (if null, not visible, if "visible", visible). I altered some forms to actually save the value so this works nice. But now I want to just show options with "visible" in database. In which function should I exactly look at? index()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your explanation I think to accomplish what you described you have to:

### Controller

```
$options = YourModelName::whereNotNull('visible')->get()->pluck('name_attr_in_db', 'id')->all();

return view('your_view_name', compact('options'));
```

### Blade

```
{!! Form::select('establishment_id[]', $options, null) !!}
```

If you don't have a good understanding of views, blades, and models, please check these links: [views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views), [models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) and [controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers)

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. But I am still getting an error of "Undefined variable: options " - I know what it means, but I can not figure out how to "declare" the option variable. I am trying to put the code in public function index() in controller, even with default listing (just replacing the variable) and it seem not to work. I have to check the documentation. Sorry for newbie questions, I am actually modifying existing code of someone else, that is why I am so confused. It seems too hard to modify anything.

Comment: In the controller section that I wrote you can see that in returning the variable at the end. The second parameter in the view method is the variables that you want inside the view

Comment: It took me a while but no I understand the structure. If I may ask, I have two database tables, Clients, and Establishments. I need somehow alter this request: Client::find($id)->establishments->pluck('select', 'id'); to take only records with "visible" in table establishments. I tried somehow combining ::whereNotNull from what you have written but got no success. How do I combine those requests? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to `Client::find($id)->establishments()->whereNotNull('visible')->get()->pluck('select', 'id')`. I would recommend using a Boolean in the database instead of a varchar for this porpuse

Comment: Man it works!!! Thank you very very much! I was trying to make it similar before but missed () at the end of establishments. I know boolean would be better, but I was just able to make it "visible" or "null", could not make 0 / 1 (int) or true / false (bool) from checkbox in editing. But well it works, even when not a perfect solution. I am just starting. Thank you very much you saved me and teached me a lot!